# Flutter facebook login token getting null

Tags: facebook, flutter, null, token

[image]

I followed every step in the tutorial but I still keep on getting this error, What could I be doing wrong? here's the code I'm using:

```
Future<void> logInWithFacebook() async {
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FacebookLogin facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();

final result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
final token = result.accessToken.token;
final graphResponse = await http.get(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token=${token}');
print(graphResponse.body);
if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn){
  final credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: token);
  _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further analyzing and research, I found out that my problem was actually facebook key hash, at first I was using the key hash generated from OpenSSL but it's not working. The working solution I came up with is to convert my SHA1 value to base64 and use the generated hash as mentioned by lucianbase in this link: https://github.com/AntonioCuevaUrraco/nativescript-facebook-login/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

```
final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
```

```html
final result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);

    switch (result.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        final token = result.accessToken.token;
        final graphResponse = await http.get(
            'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,picture,email&access_token=${token}');
        final profile = JSON.jsonDecode(graphResponse.body);
        print(profile);
        setState(() {
          userProfile = profile;
          isLoggedIn = true;

        });
        break;

      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        setState(() => isLoggedIn = false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        setState(() => isLoggedIn = false);
        break;
    }
```